# d3 drag works but appear Uncaught TypeError: a.target.className.indexOf is not a function

Tags: d3.js, svg, drag

I practice use d3 to drag svg circle around.

It works except following error appeared in console:
"Uncaught TypeError: a.target.className.indexOf is not a function"

What is wrong with my code? Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hant">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <p>
    <svg width="300" height="200">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="70" r="5" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </p>
  <script>
     var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("drag", function () {
         d3.select(this).attr("cx", d3.event.x)
                        .attr("cy",d3.event.y); 
         });
    d3.selectAll('circle').call(drag);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/pm53otue/

Comment: The error message appeared in Google chrome console.
In fact, it appeared at 'click' not at 'drag'.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors on click or drag in Chrome.

Comment: Please see the link:[link](https://github.com/hjy1210/Hello-World/blob/master/svgproblem.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It could be something caused by you running on your own machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Google Translate extension. Disabling it solves the problem.

Comment: How to go about not erroring this out if the plugin is active? Some of my users must have this plugin active. I see it erroring out in Rollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The object doesn't contain that method. This will "shim" it.

```
SVGAnimatedString.prototype.indexOf = function () { return this.baseVal.indexOf.apply(this.baseVal, arguments); }
```